Evaluating a function that returns nothing
function foo() end

if foo() then end

I saw some code that did this and wondered: What is being evaluated by the if statement when foo() does not return anything.
Tried it in an interpreter and it evaluates to false, but is that a guarantee? Is it evaluating the last thing returned somewhere else?

If control reaches the end of a function without encountering a return statement, the function implicitly returns nothing. As the syntax for if requires a single expression, the zero-length multires expression of nothing is adjusted to a single nil value.
In a control structure (if, while, repeat), a condition expression equal to nil tests false (conversely, not nil is true).
See Lua 5.4:

2.1 – Values and Types
3.3.4 – Control Structures
3.4.11 – Function Definitions
3.4.12 – Lists of expressions, multiple results, and adjustment


Nitpick: Nothing is not quite the same as nil - it's the empty vararg, which will turn into nil when used as a value. However there are scenarios in which the difference can be seen - for example print(foo()) would print a blank line rather than nil; assert(foo()) would complain about expecting a value.

@Luatic A point well made. I've tried to clarify.
